# Regex to find block of text between 2 strings not working

Tags: c#, regex

I have a csv file that has multiple reports in it.

The layout of the report is like below.  I need to pull the data out for each report and store it in a separate table.

I have a regex expression that works on regexhero.com, but when I try to implement it in c# it does not match.

Any ideas what I am getting wrong?

```
var reg = new Regex("(\"Report: Midwest Sales\")(.*?)(\"Total Records:)");
var match = reg.Matches(csvReport)
```

```
"Report: Midwest Sales"

"Order Number", "Total", "Sales Rep"

"000056","$123","Sally"

"000057","$123","Sally"

"000058,"$123","Sally"

"000059","$123","Sally"

"000060","$312","Roger"

"000061","$312","Roger"

"000062","$312","Roger"

"000063","$312","Roger"

"Total Records: 9"

"Report: Midwest Reps"

"Rep Name", "Rep Id", "Manager"

"Sally","1",""

"Roger","2","1"

"Chris","3","1"

"Gus","4","2"

"Total Records: 4"
```

Comment: try putting an @ in front of the double quotes of the Regex string, this will make it a verbatim string - backslashes won't be considered as escape characters

Comment: Also try http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: Yeah, if C# is anything like Java, then the backslashes need to be escaped. Does the @ mean the string will be interpreted as a raw string?

Comment: You're just missing the `Singleline` flag - `.` doesn't match newlines by default.

Comment: Kobi's answer fixed it, but I can't find any buttons to mark it as the answer.

Comment: You can only accept answers, not comments

Answer (score 0):

As it's a single list, you should create a conjonction a regex that match each of your different types of records.

```
((\"Report:([^\"]*"))|(\"Total Records:(.)*\")|([^\n]*))(\n|$)
```

In function of the matching groups, you will differentiate the records.